# Standard way to parse timestamp with nanoseconds

Tags: python, c

I have a timestamp created with date(1) as `date --rfc-3339=ns`. It looks like "2019-12-06 13:02:21.711339765+05:30". What is the canonical way to parse it with `strptime()` if `strptime()` does not support nanoseconds?

PS. The tag "c" is because Python uses C runtime strptime(3) function - they have the same API, so your answer may be relevant for both languages

Comment: There are some functions for handling these timestamps at https://github.com/chansen/c-timestamp . Actually, it handles timestamps with a `T` separating the date from the time instead of a space, but maybe you can work around that.

Comment: hm, so no way to do it with `strptime()`... OK

Comment: Oh, it looks like the code in link I posted handles either `T`, `t` or ` ` (space) as a separator, so maybe worth checking out. It appears to have a BSD style license.

Comment: `strptime` doesn't handle the fractional seconds, but you could maybe use it to parse some sections of the string. The POSIX standard version of `strptime` has no `%z` to parse the timezone and has nowhere in `struct tm` in which to store the UTC offset.

Comment: I guess the link I posted is no good to you for Python, although I'm sure similar stuff must exist, e.g. https://pypi.org/project/pyRFC3339/ .